# How to get localStorage value in Angular 2 template

Tags: angular, local-storage

Here is my code,

HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments | orderBy: '-'+orderBy">
    <div class="comment-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {{comment.userName}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="comment-timeago">
                    {{comment.time | timeAgo}}
                </div>
                <div class="likedicon">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o disliked" aria-hidden="true" (click)="likeComment(comment._id, comment)"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-heart liked" aria-hidden="true" *ngIf="comment.liked == 'liked'" (click)="dislikeComment(comment._id, comment)"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="like-num">
                    {{comment.like}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

File component.ts:

```typescript
likeComment(commentId, comment) {

    localStorage[commentId] = "liked";
    comment.liked = localStorage[commentId];
    comment.like ++;
    this.dataService.likeComment(commentId).subscribe(
        // Post data to server
        error => console.log(error)
    )
}

dislikeComment(commentId, comment) {
    localStorage[commentId] = "disliked";
    comment.liked = localStorage[commentId];
    comment.like --;
    this.dataService.dislikeComment(commentId).subscribe(
        // Post data to server
        error => console.log(error)
    )
```

Every comment can switch liked or disliked independently, but I have to use localStorage to decide what status should display. Maybe like:

```
*ngIf="localStorage.getItem(comment._Id) == 'liked'"
```

Unfortunately, it's the wrong syntax. I find the getter working on my other case, and the reference is from *[Angular2 How to display localStorage value inside HTML5 template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087098/angular2-how-to-display-localstorage-value-inside-html5-template)*.

In this case, I have no idea to do that, because I can't use get commentLike() in my function, neither use a global variable. How do I solve it?

Comment: did you store your `comments' in localstorage?

Comment: I don't get it. You write "I have to use localStorage to decide what status should display". If you don't store your comments in localstorage (and don't refresh them if update), how do you determine which comment is liked and which is disliked ?

Comment: Sorry, I make a misunderstanding that comments is an array, and I store each comment in comments separately like localStorage.setItem (commentId, "liked"(or "disliked")).So my localStorage is key:commentId, value: "liked" Thank you:)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you are trying to use `*ngIf="localStorage.getItem(comment._Id) == 'liked'"` it's trying to find this.localStorage in component.ts, but it doesn't exist, so it's throwing an error... Things like localStorage is common to use wherever required so keep it in global.ts which can be accessed easily...

In your `global.ts`, add a function like this:

```
export class GlobalApp {

constructor() {}

public localStorageItem(id: string): string {
    return localStorage.getItem(id);
}
```

Now update your `component.ts`:

```
import {GlobalApp} from '../helpers';

export class MyComponent {

constructor (public app: GlobalApp)  {
  }
}
```

Now it's ready to easily use in any template as we have a global declared function:

```
*ngIf="app.localStorageItem(comment._Id) == 'liked'"
```

Comment: This method is not good for performance because the call function in html is done with each change

Answer (score 0):

It is not the correct way to use localStorage like `localStorage[commentId]`. You should check it here: [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

You should use setItem and getItem.

For your case, I suggest you to use module [marcj/angular2-localstorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage).

In component:

```
@LocalStorage() public comments:any = [];
```

In your template:

```
*ngIf="comments[index]._id == 'liked'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
 selector:'app-any',
 templates:`<div *ngIf="localStorageAlice.getItem('key')">...</div>`
})
export class MyComponent {

 localStorageAlice = localStorage; 
 // to access localStorage in html use localStorageAlice.getItem('key');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use like this

In your component:

```
*ngIf="getItem(comment._Id) == 'liked'"
```

In your template:

```
getItem ( item ) { 
       return localStorage.getItem(item)
  }
```